# ggplot2::scale_x_yearqtr gives wrong year in year-quarter format plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a dataframe containing `date` column as follows:

[image]

I'm trying to plot date with format `year-quartor` by `scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%YQ%q", breaks = df$date)`, but it gives the result like this:

[image]

In fact, it should be `2019Q1, 2019Q2, ..., 2020Q3`, someone could help me figure out why it couldn't plot `date` correctly? Thanks.

Data:

```
x <- structure(list(date = structure(1:4, .Label = c("2020-03-01", 
"2020-06-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-12-01"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(12L, 34L, 15L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Code:

```
x$date <- as.Date(x$date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')

ggplot(x, aes(x = date, y = value, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  xlab('Date') +
  ylab('Value') +
  scale_x_yearqtr(format = '%YQ%q', breaks = df$date)
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I updated the code and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by adding the following code before ggplot visualization chunk:

```
df$date <- as.yearqtr(df$date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```